# magento ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE unable to add product or do any changes in backend

Tags: product

i am unable to save product after i installed my theme, it keeps on loading "Please wait" for long time and does not saves at all with below error

i get below error in console :

```
POST http://www.mywebite.com/index.php/admin/catalog_product/validate/id/61/key/xxxxxxxxx/?isAjax=true net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

and when i tried to debug network request i see below

```
http://www.mywebite.com/index.php/admin/catalog_product/validate/id/61/key/xxxxxxxxx/?isAjax=true
```

Failed to load response please guide me how to fix this error

2:**Also when u try to save to do any setting i get below error in browser**

```
No data received

ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

Is it server error or magento error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably, this is some timeout setting in the webserver configuration.
You should find corresponding errors in your webserver error log files.