# Magento2: How to fix error not showing?

Tags: magento2, error, controllers, index

> When I submit data to  saveprofile.php (controller).

**saveprofile.php**

```
use Magento\Authorization\Model\UserContextInterface as UserContextInterface;
use Magento\Authorization\Model\Acl\Role\User as RoleGroup;
use Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface;
use Medma\MarketPlace\Model\ProfileFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action;

class Saveprofile extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

   /**
    * @var \Magento\Config\Model\Config\Factory
    */
    protected $scopeConfig;

   /**
    * @var \Medma\MarketPlace\Model\ProfileFactory
    */
    protected $profile;

   /**
    * @var Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface
    */
    protected $messageManager;

   /**
    * @var \Magento\Authorization\Model\RoleFactory
    */
    protected $rolesFactory;

   /**
    * @var \Medma\MarketPlace\Helper\Data
    */
    protected $marketHelper;

   /**
    * @var \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory
    */
    protected $_fileUploaderFactory;

   /**
    * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
    */
    protected $coreregistry;

   /**
    * @var \Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManager
    */
    protected $session;

    /**
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreregistry,
     * @param \Magento\User\Model\UserFactory $adminuser,
     * @param \Medma\MarketPlace\Helper\Data $marketHelper,
     * @param \Magento\Authorization\Model\RoleFactory $rolesFactory,
     * @param \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory $fileUploaderFactory,
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManager $session,
     * @param \Medma\MarketPlace\Model\ProfileFactory $profile,
     * @param \Magento\Config\Model\Config\Factory $scopeConfig,
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager
     *
     */

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreregistry,
        \Magento\User\Model\UserFactory $adminuser,
        \Medma\MarketPlace\Helper\Data $marketHelper,
        \Magento\Authorization\Model\RoleFactory $rolesFactory,
        \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory $fileUploaderFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManager $session,
        ProfileFactory $profile,
        \Magento\Config\Model\Config\Factory $scopeConfig
    ) {
        $this->profile = $profile;
        $this->coreregistry = $coreregistry;
        $this->session = $session;
        $this->rolesFactory = $rolesFactory;
        $this->messageManager = $context->getMessageManager();
        $this->ModelUser = $adminuser;
        $this->marketHelper = $marketHelper;
        $this->_fileUploaderFactory = $fileUploaderFactory;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {

        $post = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
        $this->session->setVendorData($post);
        $model = $this->profile->create();
        $total_file_upload = $this->getRequest()->getParam('total_file_upload', false);
        $h="String";
        return $h;

    //     if ($post) {
    //         try {
    //             $data = [];
    //             $data = $post;

    //             if ($data['password']!=$data['confirmation']) {
    //                 $this->messageManager->addError(__("Entered confirm password do not matches the password"));
    //                 $this->_redirect($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
    //                 return;
    //             }

    //             $uploaded_files = [];
    //             $fileId = 'file';

    //               /**
    //              * Check files allowed
    //              **/

    //             $file_types = $this->marketHelper->getConfig('vendor_registration', 'files_allowed');
    //             $file_types = str_replace(' ', '', $file_types);
    //             $file_types_array = array_map('trim', explode(',', $file_types));


    //             /*
                //  * Check max allowed file size
                //  */


    //             $max_allowed_file_size = $this->marketHelper->getConfig('vendor_registration', 'max_allowed_file_size');
    //             $max_allowed_file_size_bytes = ($max_allowed_file_size * 1024 * 1024);


    //             /*
                //  * UPLOAD verification proof FILES
                //  */

    //             $uploaded_files = [];
    //             for ($i = 1; $i <= $total_file_upload; $i++) {
    //                 $file_control_name = 'varification_proof_' . $i;

    //                 $uploader = $this->_fileUploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => $file_control_name]);
    //                 $arr = $uploader->validateFile();


    //                 $arr[$file_control_name]['name'] = str_replace(' ', '', $arr['name']);
    //                 $arr[$file_control_name]['name'] = date("YmdHis")."-".$arr['name'];


    //                 if (isset($arr[$file_control_name]['name']) && $arr[$file_control_name]['name'] != '') {
    //                     if ($arr['size'] > $max_allowed_file_size_bytes) {
    //                         $this->messageManager->addError(__('File size should not exceed ' . $max_allowed_file_size .  ' Mb'));
    //                         $this->_redirect($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
    //                         return;
    //                     }

    //                     try {
    //                         $f_type=$arr['type'];
    //                         if ($f_type!= "image/gif" && $f_type!= "image/png" && $f_type!= "image/jpeg" && $f_type!= "image/JPEG" && $f_type!= "image/PNG" && $f_type!= "image/GIF") {
    //                             $this->messageManager->addError(__('Disallowed File Type'));
    //                             $this->_redirect($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
    //                             return;
    //                         }

    //                         $dir_path = $this->marketHelper->getImagesDir('varifications');

    //                         $uploader = $this->_fileUploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => $file_control_name]);

    //                         $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png']);
    //                         $uploader->addValidateCallback('validate', $this, 'validateFile');

    //                         $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);

    //                         $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);

    //                         $uploader->save($dir_path, $arr[$file_control_name]['name']);
    //                     } catch (\Magento\Framework\Validator\Exception $e) {
    //                         $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
    //                         $this->_redirect($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
    //                         return;
    //                     }
    //                     $uploaded_files[] = $arr[$file_control_name]['name'];
    //                 }
    //             }

    //             $roleId = $this->marketHelper->getConfig('general', 'vendor_role');

    //             $varification_files = json_encode($uploaded_files);


    //             /**
    //              * Set Data in admin user table
    //              *
    //              **/
    //             $adminuser = $this->ModelUser->create();
    //             $adminuser = $adminuser->setUsername($data['username'])
    //                                   ->setFirstname($data['firstname'])
    //                                   ->setLastname($data['lastname'])
    //                                   ->setEmail(strtolower($data['email']))
    //                                   ->setIsActive(0);

    //             /**
    //              * Set Data in authorization table
    //              *
    //              **/

    //             $role=$this->rolesFactory->create();
    //             $role->setRoleName($data['username'])
    //                  ->setRoleType(RoleGroup::ROLE_TYPE)
    //                  ->setParentId($roleId)
    //                  ->setTreeLevel(2)
    //                  ->setUserType(UserContextInterface::USER_TYPE_ADMIN);

    //             try {
    //                 if ($data['password']) {
    //                     $adminuser->setPassword($data['password']);
    //                     $result = $adminuser->validate();
    //                     $adminuser->save();
    //                     $id = $adminuser->getUserId();
    //                     $role->setUserId($id);
    //                     $role->save();
    //                 }
    //             } catch (\Magento\Framework\Validator\Exception $e) {
    //                 $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
    //                 $this->_redirect($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
    //                 return;
    //             }


    //             if (is_array($result)) {
    //                 $this->adminSession->setUserData($data);
    //                 foreach ($result as $message) {
    //                     $this->messageManager->addError($message);
    //                 }
    //                 $this->_redirect($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
    //                 return;
    //             } else {

    //                 /**
    //                  * Set Data in Marketplace Profile Table
    //                  *
    //                  **/

    //                 $data["user_id"] = $id;
    //                 $data["shop_name"] = $post["shop_name"];
    //                 $data["contact_number"] = $post["contact_number"];
    //                 $data["country"] = $post["country"];
    //                 $data["latitude"] = $post["latitude"];
    //                 $data["longitude"] = $post["longitude"];
    //               // $data["age_name"] = $post["age_name"];
    //                 $data["vendor_industry"] = $post["vendor_industry"];
    //                 $data["vendor_scorecard"] = $post["vendor_scorecard"];
    //                  /**
    //                  * Verification Files Uploaded
    //                  *
    //                  **/
    //                 if (count($uploaded_files)>0) {
    //                     $data["proof_type"] = $post["proof_type"];
    //                     $data["varification_files"] = json_encode($uploaded_files);
    //                 }


    //                 $data["create_date"] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    //                 $data["total_admin_commission"] = 0;
    //                 $data["total_vendor_amount"] = 0;
    //                 $data["total_vendor_paid"] = 0;

    //                 $model = $this->profile->create();

    //                 $model->setData($data);

    //                 /*
    //                  * Send Email
    //                  * */

    //                 $receiverInfo = [
    //                 'name' => $data['firstname'],
    //                 'email' => $data['email']
    //                 ];


    //                 try{
    //                 /* Sender Detail  */
    //                 if ($this->marketHelper->getConfig('vendor_registration_email', 'enable_registration_email')==1) {
    //                      $reciever = $this->marketHelper->getTemplateId('marketplace/vendor_registration_email/email_receiver');
    //                      $receivername = $this->marketHelper->getTemplateId('trans_email/ident_'.$reciever.'/name');
    //                      $receiveremail = $this->marketHelper->getTemplateId('trans_email/ident_'.$reciever.'/email');
    //                      $sendername = $this->marketHelper->getTemplateId('trans_email/ident_general/name');
    //                      $senderemail = $this->marketHelper->getTemplateId('trans_email/ident_general/email');


    //                      $receiverInfo = [
    //                      'name' => $receivername,
    //                      'email' => $receiveremail,
    //                      ];
    //                      $senderInfo = [
    //                      'name' => $sendername,
    //                      'email' => $senderemail,
    //                      ];

    //                      $emailTemplateVariables = [];
    //                      $emailTempVariables['myvar1'] = $data['firstname'].' '.$data['lastname'];
    //                      $emailTempVariables['myvar2'] = $receivername;

    //                      $this->marketHelper->sendRegistrationEmailToVendor(
    //                          $emailTempVariables,
    //                          $senderInfo,
    //                          $receiverInfo
    //                      );

    //                  }
    //                  /** 
    //                   * send email to vendor
    //                  */
    //                  if ($this->marketHelper->getConfig('registration_confirmation_email', 'active_vendor_email')==1) {
    //                      $vendorSender = $this->marketHelper->getTemplateId('marketplace/registration_confirmation_email/email_sender');
    //                      $vendorsendername = $this->marketHelper->getTemplateId('trans_email/ident_'.$vendorSender.'/name');
    //                      $vendorsenderemail = $this->marketHelper->getTemplateId('trans_email/ident_'.$vendorSender.'/email');

    //                      $vendorReceiverInfo = [
    //                      'name' => $data['firstname'],
    //                      'email' => $data['email']
    //                      ];
    //                      $vendorSenderInfo = [
    //                      'name' => $vendorsendername,
    //                      'email' => $vendorsenderemail,
    //                      ];

    //                      $vendorEmailTemplateVariables = [];
    //                      $vendorEmailTemplateVariables['vendorname'] = $data['firstname'];

    //                      $this->marketHelper->sendConfirmationEmail(
    //                          $vendorEmailTemplateVariables,
    //                          $vendorSenderInfo,
    //                          $vendorReceiverInfo
    //                      );

    //                  }
    //              }catch (\Exception $e) {
    //                     $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());

    //               }
    //                 $model->save();

    //                 $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Request has been sent successfully, we will contact you soon.'));
    //                 $this->_redirect($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
    //             }
    //         } catch (\Magento\Framework\Validator\Exception $e) {
    //             $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
    //             $this->_redirect($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
    //             return;
    //         }
    //     }
    //     $this->_redirect($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
    }
}
```

> But all ways showing

```
This page isn’t working www.mg.project.co didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

**Error not showing on this page**

How I can fix the issue

> I already tried

**1) index.php**

```
 error_reporting(E_ALL); 
 ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

**2) The project already in developer mode:**

[image]

**Post request not working why???**

[image: Post request image]

Comment: see this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/85159/magento-err-empty-response-unable-to-add-product-or-do-any-changes-in-backend

Comment: You should first check whether your controller execute method getting called or not. You can put all code in comment and just check by printing something that method called or not. If called, try uncommenting code one by one so you can find the culprit. If method is not called then it might be issue with routes.xml file

Comment: @prabhakaran7 check in app/bootstrap.php there you should uncomment ini_set('display_errors', 1);

Comment: @Khushbu it's going to that page but when again i remove comment it's not working

Comment: @prabhakaran7 you have to debug your code and find out which exact line of code is causing issue. you can share here that line so we can help

Comment: i debugged but it's working fine on local (no issues )

Comment: i updated the code....

Comment: have you included namespace line in top of controller in your code?

Comment: ss it's added and when i run local  it's working without error 

when on server showing like that

Comment: I can not get much idea from your code but just confirming that you have installed medma/marketplace package on your server too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94757/discussion-between-prabhakaran7-and-khushbu).

Answer (score 5):

if you're using Apache as a web server you can display error from apache error.log to your browser with adding this line code to your root `.htaccess`.

```
php_flag  display_errors                  on
php_flag  display_startup_errors          on
```

Comment: controller not working  bro

Comment: when i click on submit showing 
this error ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Comment: In my  post request has no status code (like 404,500)

Comment: I always use this method to show error when php execution get error and it's work for me, but you could check the error log manually on `/var/log/apache2/error.log` file to make sure what issue you are having.

Comment: updated one  image (post req)

Comment: in log file:  :::::

**AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /home/bbppco/mg.project.co/vendor/saveprofile**

Answer (score 2):

You are doing wrong in the following line

```
 $h="String";
 return $h;
```

You should redirect this page to any destination or you should print the response.

Solution 1.
Change  `return $h;` to  `echo $h;`

Solution 2.
Change `return $h;` to `$this->_redirect($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());`

Please mark the answer if it works for you.

Comment: $this->_redirect($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl()); what is this line actully do

Comment: This will redirect the page to the referrer page (page from you hit the controller).You can pass your own url to redirect to specific page like home page or any thank you page.

Comment: are you running company w3ctrl ........

Comment: i was working with w3ctrl.please mark answer if it's working for you.

Comment: when i  uncomment all code it's not working

Comment: comment this line return $h;

Comment: i tried....................

Comment: In my  post request has no status code (like 404,500)

Answer (score 1):

Go to your root directory and open .htaccess file.

Add the following code:

```
php_flag  display_errors                  on
php_flag  display_startup_errors          on
```

**var/log/system.log** Here, you can check the error which you are facing.

Comment: max_execution_time  180 

is that ok

Comment: @prabhakaran7, max_execution_time 2400. go for it and check with it

Comment: still i'm facing that issue bro.....

Comment: Restart server, clear cache, reindex all

Comment: In my  post request has no status code (like 404,500)

Answer (score 0):

Magento_Root/app/bootstrap.php

Line no. 12

remove `#` from this line:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

After this you will get the error

Comment: in log file: ::::: AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /home/bbppco/mg.project.co/vendor/saveprofile –

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html#access

Comment: i don't understand this document...............